# Slack github connection

Tags: commit, slack

I am the student who make the small study group which encourage programming study and commits every day.

And I want to check the commits, so I want to connect github repo in slack,
and finally find the command

```
/github subscribe githubAccount/repo
```

Can I register other members' accounts on their behalf?
Of course i test it, and register is complete. But I don't know if the notification actually comes when that person commits.
i have many member, so there is no time to wait for all members to register their accounts.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe on 'Organization' level and cover all the repos under it.
Check here :
https://github.com/integrations/slack#subscribing-and-unsubscribing